# Jekyll is not generating html for markdown pages from root folder

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I've started playing with Jekyll to move my blog to GitHub Pages. I'm using a local Jekyll tooling (`jekyll 3.1.3`) with `neo-hpstr-jekyll-theme` as a starting point on Windows.

The entry point (`index.html` in root) and posts are generated just fine. But when I place markdown file (`about.md`):

```
---
layout: page
title:  "about me"
permalink: /about
---
here goes some content with markdown syntax...
```

after build this file is placed directly under `_site\about.md` folder with exactly the same content (not transformed). It should be transformed and placed in `_site\about\index.html`

So far I've checked the layout (it exists and looks ok), BOMs in file (none is added), permalinks configuration in `_config.yml` (using the default) but with no result.

Any idea what I do wrong?

---

EDIT: The page project is available on: https://github.com/mmierzwa/mmierzwa.github.io (develop branch)

Comment: Any repository url to provide ?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/mmierzwa/mmierzwa.github.io It's on develop branch because I don't want to publish it before finishing; it contains only a sample post provided with the template and the `about.md` file I mentioned in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I do `view.encoding()` in my favorite editor, it tells me that your `about.md` is `UTF-8 with BOM` encoded.

Save it to `UTF-8 no BOM`.

Comment: Damn, I was pretty sure that I've checked that :-) Thx!